# cmake fails to pick up clang++ and always use visual studio instead on Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, clang, clang++

I have visual studio 2017 and clang both installed in a 64-bit Windows 10 PC.

```
clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
```

I have tried running cmake with clang using:

```
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
```

but cmake always pick up visual studio instead of clang as the c++ compiler.

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.13.26131.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.13.26131.
```

Is there a way to ONLY use clang as my c++ compiler in cmake without other tools like visual studio?

Comment: Maybe you should try to change the cmake generator used. -G "Ninja" ...

Comment: @MizuxDev I did not use any generator because I'm not trying to compile the code using other tools such as visual studio.

Comment: without specifying a generator cmake try to take the one which best suit the platform, and I'm not sure you can change the compiler when CMake use the default one aka "Visual Studio 15 2017"

Comment: Also did you try to set environment variable CC or CXX and/or run cmake in verbose ? for example empty CMakeLists.txt project(Bar LANGUAGES NONE) then message(STATUS "foo") enable_language(CXX) then message(FATAL_ERROR "foo") to see what's happen between both "foo"...

Comment: But I have already specified a build system, I.e. clang I don’t understand why the need of a generator? If no generator used, why does it use a native build system instead of a manually chosen one? This is quite confusing

Comment: `But I have already specified a build system, I.e. clang` - No, `clang` is not a build system, it is just a compiler. Build system cares about dependencies between files and builds files which dependencies have been updated since the last build. `clang` cannot do that. List of CMake generators, corresponded to build systems, see here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-generators.7.html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but Aren’t the dependencies taken care of by cmake itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use VisualStudio 201x with clang/c2 compiler, forgot about linux/mac approach (it works for mingw/msys etc.). There is no need to use these CMAKE_C??_COMPILER variables.

Try e.g.

```
cd build
cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017" -T "v141_clang_c2" <SRC_DIR>
```

I list of available toolsets can be observed when you open any C++ project and then look to Propertiese menu -> General: "Platform toolsets" combobox-list

Or using LLVM [snapshot build](http://llvm.org/builds/) the page define toolset names to be used in above command e.g. LLVM-vs2013.

sample output:

```
C:\work\build>cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017" -T"v141_clang_c2" <SRC>
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.8.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.8.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/ClangC2/14.10.25903/bin/HostX86/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/ClangC2/14.10.25903/bin/HostX86/clang.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
....
```

Comment: I said in my question that I don’t want cmake to use visual studio instead of clang. I am already aware of how to do it with vs but I’m more interested in how to use cmake with only clang. But according to some comments below my question it seems like I have to rely on some sort of generator.

Comment: yes, this setup will use VC as generator and define clang as compilers... (updated my response above...)

Comment: I should have explicitly said that I do not want to use visual studio as the generator due to the restrictions of the project. Perhaps I should go  for a different generator such as Ninjia.